# sync page.evaluate in phantom.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have two `page.evaluate` functions, how can I sync that? Can I pass a function as argument to `page.evaluate`? My function have two args: `selector` and `textNode`. Passing a function without args to `page.evaluate` is working (as shown in the snippet below) but I need to pass arguments to the function... I'm not sure what to do.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://web.telegram.org/#/login', function(status) {
  console.log(status)
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    page.evaluate(function(){
      document.querySelector("input[ng-model='credentials.phone_country']").value = ''
      document.querySelector("input[ng-model='credentials.phone_country']").click();
    })
    var keyNodes = '380';
    var keyNodeArr = keyNodes.split('');
    console.log(keyNodeArr)
    for(var i = 0; i < keyNodeArr.length; ++i){
      page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key[keyNodeArr[i]], null, null, null);
    }
    page.evaluate(function(){
      document.querySelector("input[ng-model='credentials.phone_number']").value = ''
      document.querySelector("input[ng-model='credentials.phone_number']").click();
    })
    keyNodes = '631091144';
    var keyNodeArr = keyNodes.split('');
    console.log(keyNodeArr)
    for(var i = 0; i < keyNodeArr.length; ++i){
      page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key[keyNodeArr[i]], null, null, null);
    }


    console.log("aa")
    page.render('github.png');
  }
  //phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: It's not clear: what you mean by "sync that"? Is there any problem with passing arguments using closure?

Answer (score 0):

By using closure I mean this (see `mySelector` and `myValue`):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://web.telegram.org/#/login', function(status) {
  console.log(status)
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    // get these from response or from whatever other source
    var mySelector = "input[ng-model='credentials.phone_country']";
    var myValue = '';

    page.evaluate(function(){
      document.querySelector(mySelector).value = myValue;
      document.querySelector(mySelector).click();
    })
    var keyNodes = '380';
    var keyNodeArr = keyNodes.split('');
    console.log(keyNodeArr)
    for(var i = 0; i < keyNodeArr.length; ++i){
      page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key[keyNodeArr[i]], null, null, null);
    }
    page.evaluate(function(){
      document.querySelector(mySelector).value = myValue;
      document.querySelector(mySelector).click();
      // or use variables with other names
      // if you need them to be different from the first ones
    })
    keyNodes = '631091144';
    var keyNodeArr = keyNodes.split('');
    console.log(keyNodeArr)
    for(var i = 0; i < keyNodeArr.length; ++i){
      page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key[keyNodeArr[i]], null, null, null);
    }


    console.log("aa")
    page.render('github.png');
  }
  //phantom.exit();
});
```